# How can I edit these columns if they do not respond to CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, flexbox

On the [tti-fl.com website](http://tti-fl.com), there are several pages with columns like these that are not responding to the CSS. I have used flex-box successfully, but these do not respond to the flex-box information for `.categories-wrapper` or `.content-block`. [Services and Solutions page with columns not responding to CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C24Xr.jpg)

My question is whether or not because they are plugins that they react differently to the CSS or that they are a different stylesheet altogether? I've tried something called `.products-wrapper`, but that is not working. I see a `#secondary li.categories`, but I am hesitant to edit these with flexbox. My questions is whether or not their CSS is somewhere hidden in the WordPress template that I have already looked? [Multiple pages have columns outside the home page.]

Comment: You are using bootstrap so your columns are already being controlled by that. It'd be asking for problems to mix the two. Either remove the bootstrapp markup/css for these columns or forget about flexbox.

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

In style.css the following:

```
.row {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  display: flex
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

needs a ; after display: flex

Comment: I did that, but the columns went down the website so I did `flex-direction:row;` and `flex: wrap` but the columns are still very small

Comment: When you say "very small", do you mean the height or the width?